# Как избежать лишнего копирования кода?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, виртуальная-функция

Я пытаюсь реализовать класс бинарной кучи с ее основными методами, но есть нюанс: с помощью шаблона хочу сделать 2 класса. Если подан false, будет куча, построенная вокруг максимума, если true - куча, построенная вокруг минимума (да, я хочу реализовать это именно с помощью шаблонов, в качестве учебного задания). Я хочу как можно больше избежать повторения кода при написании специализации false.

```
#include<iostream>
#pragma once

template<bool T>
class binaryHeap{
public:
    binaryHeap();
    ~binaryHeap();

    void insert(int);
    int getMin();
    void extractMin();
    bool isEmpty();

private:
    static const int none_val = -123;

    void siftUp(int);
    void siftDown(int);
    int* a;
    int size_;
};
```

Я пытаюсь провернуть это так (да, пока что это пустой класс):

```
template<>
class binaryHeap<false>: public binaryHeap<true>{

};
```

Собственно, вопрос: как унаследоваться так, чтобы методы `binaryHeap<true>::binaryHeap()` и `binaryHeap<true>::~binaryHeap()` совпадали с теми же в `binaryHeap<false>`, не пиша идентичного кода, или это невозможно реализовать?

*P.S Методы для полной специализации true уже реализованы в отдельном `.cpp` файле, включая `binaryHeap()` и `~binaryHeap()`*

*P.P.S может, как-то прикрутить виртуальные конструктор и деструктор?*

Comment: Если вы унаследуетесь, то получите в подарок `getMin` и `extractMin`. Это странно для максимальной кучи.

Comment: Ненадо наследовать одну специвлизвцию шаблона от другой. В тех методах, которые должны отличаться, напишите  `if constexpr  (T).{..} else{...}`, это будет проще и читабельнее.

Comment: А вы в качеств шаблона передавайте компаратор — кстати, и сразу обобщенность усилится, можно будет откалывать фокусы типа сначала четные, потом нечетные... :) Хотя, конечно, его — как и ваш true/false — можно передавать и без шаблона. Тогда и вопрос с названием `getMin` снимется — минимум *в смысле компаратора*. И, кстати, еще лучше, если уж хотите шаблонов — шаблонизируйте тип элементов кучи. P.S. И еще мне не нравится `static const int none_val = -123;` — похоже, вы используете *допустимое значение* как признак, а это чревато...

Comment: В приведенном коде не видно копирования. И непонятно, чем не угодило наследование.

Answer (score 3):

Лучше всего скопировать с `std::map`, и передавать шаблонным параметром компаратор:

```
template <typename C = std::less<>>
class BinaryHeap {...};
```

Тогда для `BinaryHeap<>` (он же `BinaryHeap<std::less<>>`) `C{}(x, y)` будет делать `x < y`.

А для обратного порядка вы бы писали `BinaryHeap<std::greater<>>`, и в нем `C{}(x, y)` уже делал бы `x > y`.

---

Или, если хотите оставить `bool`, то, как правильно советуют, используйте `if constexpr`, чтобы не городить специализации.

---

> ```
> template<>
> class binaryHeap<false>: public binaryHeap<true>
> ```

Это не будет работать без виртуальных функций, а они добавляют оверхед по памяти и по скорости.

Не стоит их использовать только для вашего удобства как автора класса. Используйте только если эта виртуальность будет полезна пользователю класса (например, общий интерфейс, который может указывать на любой из двух вариантов кучи - но это вряд ли полезно).

Обычно в таких ситуациях советуют заменить виртуальность на [CRTP](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp), чтобы не иметь оверхед. Но здесь от него толку немного, это будет сложнее чем просто буловый шаблонный параметр.

---

> ```
> binaryHeap();
> ~binaryHeap();
> ```

Забыли написать копирующие и перемещающие операции, без которых вашим классом нельзя нормально пользоваться. Это намного важнее, чем навешивание настройки порядка.

> ```
> int getMin();
> bool isEmpty();
> ```

Забыт `const` на геттерах.

---

Еще, тут напрашивается тип элемента сделать шаблонным аругментом, а не хардкодить `int`.